# Dynamically create multiple html files using php

Tags: php, javascript

my site is in php, I want my dynamic reports files converted into html file when I click on "SAVE HTML" link.

When I click on "SAVE HTML" link I want to create a new html file which contain my report which are fetched from database.

I need dynamic names when I click on save as html link date and time wise.

My code this is for one file not a dynamic file, I want dymamic html pages.

```
$SaveFile = "weeklyreport.htm";
$fh = fopen($SaveFile, "w") or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $htmlbodycontent);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

Comment: Removed the "thanks in advance" part, take a read: [FAQ - signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) and [this related meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/186879).

Answer (score 0):

Use fOpen in PHP passing the entire URL with any variables as needed to limit the scope of the document being generated and at the same time pasre the HTML that is output into a "text" file that the user will be prompted to download.

If you have just a section of PHP code that generates the reports themselves, point directly to it to stop the user saving any additional menu structure or site wrapping.

The fOpen request will be treated in exactly the same way as a normal http request, so can be parsed perfectly into a html file. You can also have the CSS written in the header/inline so that the html document will stand alone perfectly well. You will have more problems with images though.